# Null is equal to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

Im using Angular + ts.

My request looks like:

```
getOrders(this.value.id, null, null).subscribe((s) => {
  this.ordersArray = s
})
```

For some reason. `null` is converted to "null" on the server, what could be the reason for this?

**backend console**

```
    Started GET "/admin/api/as_supplier/orders.json?start=null&end=null" for ::1 at 2022-04-19 11:01:32 +0300
Processing by Admin::Api::AsSupplier::OrdersController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"start"=>"null", "end"=>"null"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Or is the problem not on the frontend, but on the backend?

**upd:**

```
 public getOrders(supplierId?: any, start?: any, end?: any): Observable<IOrders>  {
    return this.http
      .get<IOrders>(`${environment.apiUrl}/admin/api/as_supplier/orders.json`, {
        params: {
          start,
          end
        }
      })
      .pipe(tap(response => this.orders = response))
  }
```

Comment: Can you include the implementation of `getOrders` in your question's body?

Comment: I've removed the [tag:typescript] tag. This has nothing to do with TypeScript. It has to do with how/whether your server code does post-processing on the GET parameters to change them into something other than string (since all query parameters are fundamentally strings).

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Upd

Answer (score 2):

you should do something like this:

```
let params = new HttpParams();
if (start !== null && start !== undefined) {
    params = params.set('start', start);
}
if (end !== null && end !== undefined) {
    params = params.set('end', end);
}

return this.http.get<IOrders(`${environment.apiUrl}/admin/api/as_supplier/orders.json`, {params})
```

Comment: I removed ``!== null`` as I need to send ``null``. But still it didn't work. null is also translated into a string.

Comment: params can either be `string``number` or `boolean`. a param can't be null. 
if you don't send the param, then ist's null.
Alternatively you can send an empty string ""

Answer (score 1):

@Alex i think the problem in your server side, try to parse params before you use it in the rest of your code in API